# Make the jquery script smart

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

There are 3 input fields.
Each has its own hidden input which helds value.

At this moment script works only for Bananas.(:-))

1 Banana is worth 1 banana OR 0.5 apple or 0.021 of a cookie(in other words 1 apple = 2 bananas, 46 bananas = cookie, 1 banana = 1 banana).

What I would like this script to do is to calculate values also for Apples and Cookies, and sum them up to show how much are they worth in "other" currencies.(for example show the price of 3 apples and 4 cookies in all 3 currencies)

I do realise that the code is very...well it would be a shame to call it code.

I just don't have any idea how to do it;

Any help would very appreciated.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/9/

HTML:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
Apple<input name="inputone" id="inputone" class="calc" value="0"><span id="TotalOne"></span>
            </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
Banana<input name="inputtwo" id="inputtwo" class="calc" value="0"><span id="TotalTwo"></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
                    <tr>
        <td>
Cookie<input name="inputthree" id="inputthree" class="calc" value="0"><span id="TotalThree"></span>
            </td>
            </tr>
</table>
    <input name="multiplierone" id="multiplierone" class="calc" value="1" type="hidden" readonly>
    <input name="multipliertwo" id="multipliertwo" class="calc" value="0.5" type="hidden" readonly>
            <input name="multiplierthree" id="multiplierthree" class="calc" value="23" type="hidden" readonly>
    <input type="button" id="update" value="Calculate" />
```

JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('#update').click(function() { 
        var inputone = $('#inputone').val();
        var multiplierone = $('#multiplierone').val();
        var inputtwo = $('#inputtwo').val();
        var multipliertwo = $('#multipliertwo').val();
        var inputthree = $('#inputthree').val();
        var multiplierthree = $('#multiplierthree').val();
        var totalTotalOne = (inputtwo * multipliertwo);
        var totalTotalTwo = (inputtwo);
        var totalTotalThree = (inputtwo / multiplierthree / 2);
        $('#TotalOne').text(totalTotalOne);
        $('#TotalTwo').text(totalTotalTwo);
        $('#TotalThree').text(totalTotalThree);
    });
});
```

Comment: What are you comparing the currencies against? what's the baseline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from what i gather from you description is that you want to get an amount that you have of a particular item. So if you have 10 bananas you want to calculate those 10 bananas against the other elements. The same goes for if you have 37 cookies you want to know how much its worth against the other items.

I believe that if you were to simplify your UI into two elements one being a input text field to enter amounts and another radio check collection, or it could be a selection field to select what type you have it will make better sense.

In your current setup you are not taking into account that your type(Apple, Banana, cookie) variable will change its only hard-coded to calculate bananas.

I quickly setup a jsbin to show you what i mean. Its just a start that may help you think of something else to do. Happy coding!

http://jsbin.com/EKisiGIK/10/edit

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#update').click(function() {
   var inputone = parseFloat($('#inputone').val());
    var multiplierone = parseFloat($('#multiplierone').val()); 
    var inputtwo =parseFloat( $('#inputtwo').val());
    var multipliertwo = parseFloat($('#multipliertwo').val());
    var inputthree =parseFloat( $('#inputthree').val());       
    var multiplierthree = parseFloat($('#multiplierthree').val());
     var totalTotalOne = (inputtwo * multipliertwo);           
     var totalTotalTwo = (inputtwo); 
     var totalTotalThree = (inputtwo / multiplierthree / 2); 
      $('#TotalOne').text(totalTotalOne); 
      $('#TotalTwo').text(totalTotalTwo); 
      $('#TotalThree').text(totalTotalThree); 
    });
 });
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do to make this problem simpler is to convert all currencies to a base currency before converting to their respective currencies. Using the example you have given i have converted all the currencies to their `Cookie` equivalent as it was the most valuable therefore removing the need to work with decimal values.

Change the HTML to

```
<input name="multiplierone" id="multiplierone" class="calc" value="23" type="hidden" readonly>
<input name="multipliertwo" id="multipliertwo" class="calc" value="46" type="hidden" readonly>
<input name="multiplierthree" id="multiplierthree" class="calc" value="1" type="hidden" readonly>
```

which is how many of each of the currencies it takes to make up one `Cookie`.
The following code can then be used to convert the currencies to `Cookies`

```
var base_total = inputone / multiplierone + inputtwo / multipliertwo + inputthree / multiplierthree;
var totalTotalOne = (base_total * multiplierone);
var totalTotalTwo = (base_total * multipliertwo);
var totalTotalThree = (base_total * multiplierthree);
```

this code will convert all the separate input values into their equivalent `Cookie` value. Once you have a total of all the fields as a cookie value it is a simple matter to convert that value back to all the respective currency values.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/10/)